# Rails 3: Filtering results by counting children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm working on an approval system where an example would be filtered out if it had more negative approvals than positive.

```
class Set < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :examples
end

class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :approvals, as: :approvable
end

class Approval < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :approvable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :example
  attr_accessible :choice #boolean
end
```

I can get all approvals belonging to an Example by calling `Example.approvals`.

What i'm wondering about is if it's possible to create a method on Example model that i could then use a la `Example.approved` that would return true or false with a single query depending on if the example has more Approvals with true or false. Ultimately i would want to call only the examples of a set that have been approved by calling `Set.approved_examples`.

Example.approved i can kind of do with

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def approved
    if approvals.where(choice: true).count > approvals.where(choice: false).count
      return true
    end
    false
  end
end
```

although that takes two queries.

`Set.approved_examples` would look like the SQL View approved_examples in [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d42fd/1) but i'm not sure where to start if i wanted a scope like this on the Set model.

Comment: use counter cache for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, based on your comment I think I misunderstood your question but maybe you coudld try something like this:

```
Example.all.select { |example| example.approved == true }
```

That would get you an array of all approved examples.

```
Set.first.examples.all.select { |example| example.approved == true }
```

That would get you an array of all approved examples that belong to the first set record.

I think there's probably a more optimal way to do this, but this does work.

Comment: What im wondering about though is how to get a relation or array of all the examples that are approved. Is it possible to make a Set.approved_examples method or scope like this?

Comment: That would be exactly what i want but im not sure if virtual attributes can be used in scopes. (Rails trying to find "examples"."approved" = t). Maybe ill try to update an approved column for examples table kind of what is done on counter cache.

Comment: Edit: Ah, looked at earlier notes. These commands work just fine!